# explain java bytecode

Tags: disassembly, java, byte-code

I saw java bytecode that need to compare to var,
if they equal return true, else .....

```
if(var1==var2)
   return true;
else
{ ...}
```

on bytecode

```
aload 1
aload 2
if_acmpne 6
iconst 1
ireturn
```

I understand iconst1 and ireturn to return true. and understand aload1 and aload2 to load 2 var to stack.

But how `if_acmpne 6` works? what is 6?
thank

Comment: 6 is a label/branchoffset. If the comparison shows that the two values are not equal, then execution jumps to the instruction at location 6 (in your example, that is). Good resources here (https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--24.html) and here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

Comment: @dsasmblr in this case 6  is that mean  instruction  no..6  from the beginning of my function? is that depend on my os or on somthing else? or 6 is always  instruction  no. 6?

Answer (score 1):

The `if_acmpne` instruction pops two objects off the stack and compares them. If they are not equal, then it jumps to the provided offset, which in this case is 6 bytes from the start of the method code.

In general, you can learn about all of the bytecode instructions by reading the JVM specification here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Comment: in this case 6  is that mean  instruction  no..6  from the beginning of my function? is that depend on my os or on somthing else? or 6 is always  instruction  no. 6?

Comment: Instruction sizes are defined by the bytecode format and are OS independent. Most instructions are one byte long (hence the term bytecode), but some are longer. `if_acmpne` itself is 3 bytes for instance. Again, you really need to read the JVM spec.

Comment: I read the JVM spec, but when i open this class with Krakatau that show that the number that come after if_acmpne define lable name

Comment: @cdcsccd That's the assembler being helpful. Working with the raw bytes directly is a huge pain, so assemblers define a human readable format which can be mapped to and from the underlying binary classfile. If you want to see the raw classfile, use a hex editor.